# Basic Python Question: elif Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to Python, and am trying to figure out how the indentation works as opposed to brackets. I'm  having a problem with elif:

```
"""This program calculates the area of a circle or triangle."""
print "Area Calculator is on."
option = raw_input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ")
if option == 'C': radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius: ")) 
  area = 3.14159*radius**2
  print "The area of circle with radius %s is %s." % (radius, area)
elif option == 'T':
    base = float(rawinput("Enter the base: "))
    height = float(rawinput("Enter the height: "))
    area2 = .5*base*height
    print "The area of triangle with base %s and height %s is %s." % (base, height, area2)

else: print "ERROR"
```

Whenever I try submitting this, it gives me an invalid syntax error at the elif. I have tried looking at different threads about this, but those had elif indented too far, or else forgot to put the colon at the end of elif. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: show complete error message

Comment: put a line break after the `if option == 'C':` part and make sure that the `radius = ...` line is aligned with the `area = ...` line. Whitespace and indentation are very important in python.

Comment: you have an invalid indent before `area = 3.14159*radius**2` because `radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius: "))` is in the same line as the `if`. Then, you're using both `raw_input` and `rawinput`

Comment: The code you've posted would produce a SyntaxError, but not at the elif.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a very unforgiving language when it comes to indentation. The [PEP-8 style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guide will do you good here, but the issues with your code were inconsistent indentation after the `if` and then after the `elif` (2 vs. 4 spaces), and the run on variable declaration following the colon in the `if`.

Here is a revised version of your Python 2 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

"""This program calculates the area of a circle or triangle."""
print "Area Calculator is on."
option = raw_input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ")
if option == 'C':
    radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius: ")) 
    area = 3.14159*radius**2
    print "The area of circle with radius %s is %s." % (radius, area)
elif option == 'T':
    base = float(raw_input("Enter the base: "))
    height = float(raw_input("Enter the height: "))
    area2 = .5*base*height
    print "The area of triangle with base %s and height %s is %s." % (base, height, area2)
else:
    print "ERROR"
```

Comment: I see. You are correct pointing that out, but it runs fine on my machine. I'm afraid I don't fully understand the problem then.

Comment: lol. I see the error now. I updated my code and changed `rawinput` to `raw_input`. Seems to work now for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 2 or 3..

I am in Python 3 and run your code after few changes and it works fine. Please try :

```
print ("Area Calculator is on.")
option = input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ")
if option == 'C':
    radius = float(input("Enter the radius: "))
    area = 3.14159*radius**2
    print ("The area of circle with radius %s is %s." % (radius, area))
elif option == 'T':
    base = float(input("Enter the base: "))
    height = float(input("Enter the height: "))
    area2 = .5*base*height
    print ("The area of triangle with base %s and height %s is %s." % (base, height, area2))
else: 
    print ("ERROR")
```

Comment: It has to be python 2 based on the print statement

Comment: Thanks Pault... Print and other staements can be changed by user as per version.. I have corrected the mistakes like intendation, replaced Rawinput with RAW_Input and it work.

Comment: I'm sorry. This was a very stupid mistake on my part, and I will definitely learn from it.